# Why is resume from hibernate not working?

Tags: 14.04, hibernate

I have just installed 14.04LTS and set up home dir encryption and Swap partition encryption using Keyfile and LUKS. All using this guide: [Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto3)

Swap is availave and system hibernates. But cannot resume from disk, just resume from ram is working. How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jhonnytunes,
This comes in late, but you will find food for thought and action [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelHibernate). What you experieince seems to be a documented bug. If you find a work-around or (better yet!) a solution, please post it here in extenso.-

Comment: Never mind I just reinstalled the ubuntu again without the encryption. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnableHibernateWithEncryptedSwap) you can use encrypted swap with a fixed key which is needed every time started or resumed from hibernate.