# Black screen after waking up from Hibernation

Tags: 14.04, hibernate

My `hibernate` feature on `Ubuntu 14.04` is working fine when I am not running any program or heavy programs. However, when I am running programs such as Google Chrome, then after waking up from Hibernation, it just shows a black blank screen, with a cursor initially. Eventually the cursor fades away and nothing happens. I waited for 8/10 minutes, but nothing happens. Is this a memory problem? If yes, then how can I increase that memory?

Here's my graphics card:
`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)` (In case anyone thinks it's an issue.)

Answer (score 0):

I actually happened to have that issue on Kubuntu - though after a restart. I have been reading through the forums and through the web and found, that killing the plasmashell and then restarting it fixed the issue.

It would be helpful to know which System you are running? Kubuntu? Ubuntu? If you are running Kubuntu, you can try to kill and restart the plasmashell as well. Try `killall plasmashell` or `kill plasmashell` then restart it, using `kstart plasmashell`.

You can do so by changing to one of the terminals, using `CTRL+ALT 1 to 6`. In some cases, changing to the terminal and back to the UI fixed the issue as well. To go back to the UI / Desktop you can use `CTRL+ALT 7`.

Oh one more question: Do you happen to have home directory encryption enabled during install? There is an issue with that, as you can see [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509159/why-is-resume-from-hibernate-not-working?rq=1). In this case resintalling without home directory encryption should fix it.

Comment: Well, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: See my edit. Did you enable home directory encryption? Check the link in my answer.. might be that one... I am on Kubuntu, so I don't know about Ubuntu but you can try search their forums. If it is a bug or an issue it's there...

Comment: Thank you. However, if the encryption was issue, then it should not have waken up any time. But it's waking up when not much programs are running.