# Increase linux-swap partition for hibernation

Tags: partitioning, swap, hibernate

I am having [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731851/black-screen-after-waking-up-from-hibernation) when I hibernate Ubuntu 14.04 . I want to increase my `linux-swap` memory to 25-30 GB. Currently it's around 15 GB as it can be seen in the picture below. My RAM is 8 GB. Can anyone please help me increase the size of the `linux-swap` memory to 25-30 GB?

[image: GParted Disk Partition]

Comment: That is a surprising amount of swap space; what exactly are you doing that needs that much?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know why I need that much space. However, I just want to try it out because Hibernate is not working when I am running multiple programs such as Eclipse, TeXStudio. Without those programs, Hibernate works just fine.

Comment: I don't think nowadays linux requires a lot of swap space? Moreover in that thread that you mentioned...nowhere it says increase swap for this purpose?

Comment: Is there any other reason of the hibernation problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of gparted to increase the size of swap partition from the current 15GB to 30 GB. You can release some space from /home  - make around 15 GB from that and add into your swap. Make sure you are backing up your important data while doing that. Moreover whatever changes you are trying to do make sure that the partition is unmounted.
Here is how you can do that:

1. Make sure that /dev/sda9 is unmounted. If a lock icon is visible,
   right click on it and choose for Unmount
2. Make sure that the swap partition /dev/sda10 is unmounted. Right
   click on it and choose for Swapoff
3. Select /dev/sda9 and choose for Resize. Use the free space on the
   left side
4. Select /dev/sda10 and resize it on the right side Apply the changes
   and you're done.

Note : I will say one thing at a time...first release space from /dev/sda9  write the changes. Then add the released space from previous step to /dev/sda10